# iteritems: match k value lower/upper and white space

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a dictionary in Python 2.7.

Below is the code:

```
d = {}
with open('input') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == 'items':
```

In input file they mention some times "items" like below:

```
items:
Items:
ITEMS:
     Items  :
```

I want to match all of above in my code that is Now I am using

```
k == "items":
```

This does not work if "items" in upper case or has whitespaces.

Please help to fix my script.

Comment: what are you doing with values with `'items'` key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine k to lowercase and remove whitespace with

```
k = k.lower().strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) methods:

```
d = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k.lower().strip() == 'items':
        # do work with single value
```

---

If you need to process values with similar keys, it may be a good idea to collect them into a `list` on step of `d` object creation.

We can do this with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method

```
d = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        key = key.lower().strip()
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

values = d['items']  # or use `d.get('items', [])` if there may not be 'items' key
# do work with multiple values
```

or with `dict` extension – [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        key = key.lower().strip()
        d[key].append(value)

values = d['items']
# do work with multiple values
```